# Can Picard groups be computed on closed points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $X$ is a quasiprojective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$, thought of as a scheme. Is the Picard group of the $X$, in the sense of schemes, isomorphic to the Picard group, in the classical sense, of the underlying quasiprojective variety $X(k)$ whose points are the closed points of $X$?

I feel like the answer should be "yes", but I have not been able to find a reference. Here's how I think the argument should go. First, as $X(k)$ is very dense in $X$ (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615709/is-the-set-of-closed-points-of-a-k-scheme-of-finite-type-dense)), the lattices of open sets on $X$ and $X(k)$ coincide. Since Picard groups can be computed from Cech cohomology, i.e. $Pic(X) = \check{H}^1(X, \mathcal{O}^*_X)$ and $Pic(X(k)) = \check{H}^1(X(k),\mathcal{O}^*_{X(k)})$, the fact that $\mathcal{O}_X^*(A) = \mathcal{O}^*_{X(k)}(A(k))$ for any open affine subscheme $A\subset X$, seems to imply that there is an isomorphism 
$$Pic(X)\rightarrow Pic(X(k))$$ 
obtained by sending a line bundle on $X$ to its restriction to $X(k)$.

Comment: Seems right. I mean to know about a line bundle you need to know what the open sets are and what the functions are, and the closed points see all of that. I'd be curious to know if someone has written down a GAGA-type statement about modules on both sides of the functor $\mathfrak{Var} \to \mathfrak{Sch}$. Maybe it's trivial.

Comment: @Hoot It is trivial, as you pointed out. If one wants to drudge through all the details it's in Gortz and Wedhorn I believe.

Comment: @Hoot Thanks for your response. Regarding "I'd be curious to know if someone has written down a GAGA-type statement about modules on both sides of the functor Var --> Sch". I was also wondering about this. Maybe there is an equivalence of categories between vector bundles (maybe even coherent sheaves) on $X$ and those on $X(k)$? Would you happen to know, @Alex? (I skimmed Görtz-Wedhorn by the way, but the answer didn't immediately jump out at me.)