# Set of Closed points of a Quasi-projective variety is dense

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-varieties

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $V$ be a Qausi-projective variety in $\mathbb P^n_k$ i.e. $V$ is an open subset of an open subset of a Zariski-closed subset of  $\mathbb P^n_k$, or in other words, $V$ is an intersection of a Zariski-closed and a Zariski-open subset of $\mathbb P^n_k$ .

Let $\mathcal C(V):=\{p\in V: \{p\} $ is closed in $V \}$.

How do I prove that $\mathcal C(V)$ is dense in $V$ ?

I have seen the post here [Is the set of closed points of a $k$-scheme of finite type dense?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615709/is-the-set-of-closed-points-of-a-k-scheme-of-finite-type-dense)  for general schemes of finite type, but every proof uses some quite heavy-tools. For the specific case of my question, can we give a more elementary proof ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically a restatement of the Nullstellensatz (or a slightly weakened version of it; the full strength of the Nullstellensatz says not just that closed points are dense but that $k$-points are dense).  We may assume actually $V\subseteq\mathbb{A}^n_k$ (just consider the intersection of $V$ with each $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ covering $\mathbb{P}^n_k$).  We may also assume $V$ is closed in $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ (since $V$ is open in its closure, so if closed points are dense in its closure they are also dense in $V$).  Say $V$ is defined by the ideal $I\subseteq k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.  Our goal is then to show any nonempty open subset of $V$ contains a closed point.

A nonempty open subset of $V$ is a union of sets of the form $D(f)\cap V$ for $f\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, where $D(f)\cap V$ is the set of prime ideals in $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ which contain $I$ but do not contain $f$.  Such prime ideals are in bijection with prime ideals in the ring $(k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I)[f^{-1}]\cong k[x_1,\dots,x_n,y]/(I+(1-yf))$.  So if $D(f)\cap V$ is nonempty, the ring $k[x_1,\dots,x_n,y]/(I+(1-yf))$ is nonzero and $I+(1-yf)$ is a proper ideal of $k[x_1,\dots,x_n,y]$.  By the Nullstellensatz, this means there exists $(a_1,\dots,a_n,b)\in k^{n+1}$ on which every element of $I+(1-yf)$ vanishes.  This just means that every element of $I$ vanishes on $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $bf(a_1,\dots,a_n)=1$, so in particular $f(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is nonzero.  This means the maximal ideal in $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ corresponding to $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in k^n$ is a closed point of $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ which is in $V\cap D(f)$.  This shows any nonempty open subset of $V$ contains a closed point, so closed points are dense in $V$.