# Is there a hypothesis missing in this statement of the See-Saw principle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, schemes

In Huybrecht's 'Fourier-Mukai Transforms in Algebraic Geometry', the see-saw principle is stated in Proposition 9.4 as follows.

> Let $X$ be an irreducible complete variety over a field $k$, $T$ an integral scheme, and $L \in \operatorname{Pic}(X \times T)$. Suppose $L_t:=L|_{X \times \{t\}}$ is trivial for all closed points $t \in T$. Then there exists a line bundle $M$ on $T$ with $L \cong p^*M$.
> (where $p: X \times T \to T$ is the canonical projection)

In the proof sketch, it is explained that being trivial is a closed condition on $T$. From this, it is concluded that checking closed points is enough.

I interpreted this closed condition to mean $\{t \in T\;|\;L_t\text{ is trivial}\} \subset T$ is a closed subset. The conclusion then seems to rely on the assumption that closed points are dense, which I don't think is in general true for integral schemes. Perhaps there is some implicit assumption that $T$ is of finite type over $k$? In this case, [closed points are indeed dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615709/is-the-set-of-closed-points-of-a-k-scheme-of-finite-type-dense).

Am I missing the point here or are there missing hypotheses in the theorem statement?

Thank you!

Comment: $ T $ being integral + quasi-compact is enough. But yes, I also do not see how to conclude the result by assuming that $ T $ is just integral.

Comment: @CraniumClamp Is this sufficient to have closed points being dense?